# How to sort my xml file correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, sorting, xna

I have a problem with a game im making. Im trying to sort the highscore list but its not working as intended. When saving the score I get in the game I want to look through the highscore list and check if its higher than a score in the list and if so put the new highscore in the list and move the other scores down in the list.
Code looks like this:

```
public void SaveHighScore(int score)
    {
        // Create the data that needs to be saved
        HighScore data = LoadHighScores(HighScoresFilename);
        int scoreIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (score >= data.Score[i])
            {
                scoreIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (scoreIndex >= 0)
        {
            int[] tempScore = new int[5];
            for (int i = 4; i >= scoreIndex; i--)
            {
                tempScore[i] = data.Score[i];
            }

            tempScore[scoreIndex] = score;

            for (int i = scoreIndex; i > 0; i--)
            {
                tempScore[i - 1] = data.Score[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < data.Score.Length; i++)
                data.Score[i] = tempScore[i];


            SaveHighScores(data, HighScoresFilename);
        }
    }
```

And my class looks like this: https://github.com/PalmerVincent/Game/projects

The problem is that the highscore list does not get sorted correctly if a new highscore is put into the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml format is not a issue for you, I suggest that you can create a simple Player Class and use List...

```
public class Player
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
}

public int Count
public List<Player> Players

public HighScore()
{  
  Players = new List<Player>();
}

//your initialize
public static void Initialize()
{
   string fullpath = "";
   HighScore data;

   if (!File.Exists(fullpath))
   {

            Player player = new Player { Name = "Neil", Score = 20 };
            Player player1 = new Player { Name = "Shawn", Score = 15 };
            Player player2 = new Player { Name = "Mark", Score = 10};
            Player player3 = new Player { Name = "Cindy", Score = 5 };
            Player player4 = new Player { Name = "Sam", Score = 1 };
            data.Players.Add(player);
            data.Players.Add(player1);
            data.Players.Add(player2);
            data.Players.Add(player3);
            data.Players.Add(player4);

            SaveHighScores(data, fullpath);
   }
}

 public static void SaveHighScore(int score, string name)
 {
        HighScore data = LoadHighScores(HighScoresFilename);

        var player = data.Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Vincent");

        // new player in town
        if(player == null)
        {
            Player newPlayer = new Player { Name = "Vincent", Score = score };

            data.Players.Add(newPlayer);

            data.Players = data.Players.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Score).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            //set new score
            player.Score = score;
            data.Players = data.Players.OrderByDescending(o => o.Score).ToList();
        }

        data.Count = data.Players.Count;
        SaveHighScores(data, HighScoresFilename);
}
```

and check your xml

```
HighScore.SaveHighScore(12, "Vincent");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel when it comes to sorting. C# comes with a few sort methods, and there are open source projects as well that you can use.

But, in your case you aren't sorting. You have a simple list, with the highest score at the top of the list. The rest are in descending order of score values.

So, the MaxScore would be, borrowing from `canar's` `Player` class.

```
public int MaxScore { return list[0].Score; }
public int MaxScorer { return list[0].Name; }
```

And to borrow from the method definition `canar` created.

```
public static void SaveHighScore(int score, string name) 
{
    var list = LoadHighScores();
    // verify score is > first score to make sure list stays sorted
    if (list.Count > 0 && score <= list[0].Score)
        return; // invalid high score

    Player player = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
    if (player != null)
    {
        list.Remove(player);
        player.Score = score;
    }
    else
        player = new Player { Name = name, Score = score };
    list.InsertAt(0, player);
    SaveHighScores(list);
}
```